# Agregar datos con entity framework a mi tabla de MySQL

Tags: mysql, c#, .net, entity-framework

estoy añadiendo entity framework a mi proyecto, queria saber si habia una forma de agregar datos a mi base de MySQL , y en caso de que ya existan estos datos que no se agreguen, el ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente>? Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comprobantes>? Comprobantes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comprobantes_Tipo>? Comprobantes_Tipo { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
       optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=db_storesys_test;user=root;port=3306;password=15648836");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente>(usuarioCuentaCorriente =>
        {
            usuarioCuentaCorriente.HasKey(e => e.clienteCuentaCorrienteId);
            usuarioCuentaCorriente.Property(e => e.comprobanteId).IsRequired();
            usuarioCuentaCorriente.HasOne(x => x.Comprobante).WithOne(p => p!.usuarioCuentaCorriente);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Comprobantes>(comprobante =>
        {
            comprobante.HasKey(e => e.comprobanteId);
            comprobante.Property(e => e.comprobanteDescripcion).IsRequired();
            comprobante.HasOne(e => e.comprobanteTipo).WithOne(p => p!.Comprobante);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Comprobantes_Tipo>(comprobanteTipo =>
        {
            comprobanteTipo.HasKey(e => e.comprobanteTipoId);
            comprobanteTipo.Property(e => e.descripcion).IsRequired();
            comprobanteTipo.HasOne(x => x.Comprobante).WithOne(p => p!.comprobanteTipo);
        });

        //modelBuilder.Entity<Comprobantes_Tipo>().HasData(
        //    new Comprobantes_Tipo 
        //    { 
        //        comprobanteTipoId = 1,
        //        descripcion = "PEDIDO"
        //    },
        //    new Comprobantes_Tipo 
        //    {
        //        comprobanteTipoId = 2,
        //        descripcion = "COMPROBANTE DE DEUDA"
        //    },
        //    new Comprobantes_Tipo
        //    {
        //        comprobanteTipoId = 3,
        //        descripcion = "FACTURA A"
        //    });
    }

    public void agregarDatos()
    {
        try
        {
            using (DataBaseContext context = new DataBaseContext())
            {
                //AGREGAMOS COMPROBANTES TIPO
                List<Comprobantes_Tipo> listaComprobantesTipo = new List<Comprobantes_Tipo>();
                listaComprobantesTipo.Add(new Comprobantes_Tipo { comprobanteTipoId = 1, descripcion = "PEDIDO" });
                listaComprobantesTipo.Add(new Comprobantes_Tipo { comprobanteTipoId = 2, descripcion = "COMPROBANTE DE DEUDA" });
                listaComprobantesTipo.Add(new Comprobantes_Tipo { comprobanteTipoId = 3, descripcion = "FACTURA A" });
                listaComprobantesTipo.Add(new Comprobantes_Tipo { comprobanteTipoId = 4, descripcion = "FACTURA B" });
                context.Comprobantes_Tipo.AddRange(listaComprobantesTipo);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
}
```

En mi tabla de "Comprobantes_Tipo" ya existen los siguientes registros:
1              PEDIDO
2              COMPROBANTE DE DEUDA
3              FACTURA A

Y quiero agregar el cuarto registro, que seria.
4              FACTURA B

Pero me tira error cuando corro el metodo "agregarDatos()" porque me dice que se esta duplicando el Id 1, es decir que el Id 1 ya existe en mi base de datos MySQL, queria saber si hay alguna forma de verificar si el registro ya existe, y que si ya existe no lo inserte en la base y si no existe si lo inserte

Espero haber sido claro y muchas gracias!

Comment: podrias agregar un id autoincremental y asi no tener duplicados?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, lo que yo hago en esos casos es hacer una consulta a db para verificar si el ID ya existe para devolver un mensaje de "dato ya existente" o en caso contrario, realizar el guardado.